# Limit get_pages to only show 5 items

Tags: php, pages

How can I limit the get_pages to only show 5 items?

I thought adding `'number' => 5` to the array would limit it to 5 but it doesn't show anything. Here's my code:

```
<?php 
$pages = get_pages(array('post_type' => 'page','sort_column' => 'menu_order','sort_order' => 'ASC','child_of' => 765));

foreach($pages as $post)
{
setup_postdata($post);
$fields = get_fields();
?>
        <p><?php echo $fields->start_date; ?> <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($post->ID) ?>"><?php echo substr($fields->event_title,0,24) . "..."; ?></a></p>
<?php
}

wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: is it possible that you had a typing error or got the syntax wrong? unfortunately your posted code does not show your trial.

Comment: Syntax all correct, seems there's a bit of a problem with it. Get_children seemed to work though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had similar problems with the `number` attribute in `get_pages()`

I got around it by using [get_children](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children):

```
$pages = get_children(array(
   'numberposts' =>1,
   'post_parent' => $heading_page->post_id
   ));
```

and using `post_parent` instead of `child_of`.

Comment: That worked, thanks. Get_pages just would not work whichever way I did it!

Comment: I've never actually posted a bug report for wordpress but this seems like a likely candidate allright

Comment: Yep definitely! All the suggestions from other people don't seem to work and I've had trouble with it before.